# Second order DE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for tips for this equation: $ 4xy''+y'+xy'+\frac{3}{2}y=0 $. I am solving with the substitution y=a(x)b(x), but it is getting messy..

Comment: I am afraid that it will be messy whatever you do except what Amzoti suggested (not surprizing).

Comment: Ill try with series, but it will be difficult :) Frobenius methods? Thanks, Ill search about that